# Implementing Laravel old data in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, beginner, php, laravel, vue.js

Users input their pin-code which is checked against the database and returned with the locality, district and state associated with that pin-code. Multiple localities may be returned so the options are passed to a select element so the user can choose theirs.

Old values are also passed as props to the Vue component and displayed in event of server side validation error.

### Vue Component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <b-form-group class="col-6" label="Pincode" label-for="pincode">
                <b-form-input
                    id="pincode"
                    name="pincode"
                    v-model="pincode"
                    placeholder="Pincode"
                    type="number"
                    min="100000"
                    max="999999"
                    :state="pincodeState"
                ></b-form-input>
                <b-form-invalid-feedback id="pincode-live-feedback">
                    Pincode must be 6 digits
                </b-form-invalid-feedback>
            </b-form-group>
            <b-form-group
                class="col-6"
                label="Locality (Please Select)"
                label-for="locality"
            >
                <b-form-select
                    id="locality"
                    name="locality"
                    class="form-control"
                    v-model="locality"
                    :options="l_options"
                    :state="pinValid"
                >
                </b-form-select>
                <b-form-invalid-feedback id="locality-live-feedback">
                    Pincode doesn't exist
                </b-form-invalid-feedback>
            </b-form-group>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <b-form-group class="col-6" label="District" label-for="district">
                <b-form-input
                    id="district"
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    v-model="district"
                    :state="pinValid"
                    disabled
                ></b-form-input>
                <b-form-invalid-feedback id="district-live-feedback">
                    Pincode doesn't exist
                </b-form-invalid-feedback>
            </b-form-group>
            <b-form-group class="col-6" label="State" label-for="state">
                <b-form-input
                    id="state"
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    v-model="state"
                    :state="pinValid"
                    disabled
                ></b-form-input>
                <b-form-invalid-feedback id="state-live-feedback">
                    Pincode doesn't exist
                </b-form-invalid-feedback>
            </b-form-group>
            <input type="text" hidden name="district" :value="district" />
            <input type="text" hidden name="state" :value="state" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "AddressReceiver",
    props: {
        p_old: {
            default: null,
        },
        l_old: {
            default: null,
        },
        d_old: {
            default: null,
        },
        s_old: {
            default: null,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            pincode: this.p_old,
            locality: this.l_old,
            l_options: [],
            district: this.d_old,
            state: this.s_old,
            pincodeState: null,
            pinValid: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        pincodeSearch() {
            axios
                .get("/api/pincode/" + parseInt(this.pincode))
                .then((response) => {
                    this.pinValid = true;
                    this.resetIn();
                    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        this.l_options.push(response.data[i].locality);
                    }
                    if (this.l_old) {
                        this.locality = this.l_old;
                    } else {
                        this.locality = response.data[0].locality;
                    }
                    this.district = response.data[0].district;
                    this.state = response.data[0].state;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.pinValid = false;
                    this.resetIn();
                });
        },
        resetIn() {
            this.l_options = [];
            this.locality = null;
            this.district = null;
            this.state = null;
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        if (this.p_old) {
            this.pincode = this.p_old;
            this.pincodeSearch();
        }
    },
    watch: {
        pincode(newPin) {
            if (newPin >= 100000 && newPin <= 999999) {
                this.pincodeSearch();
                this.pincodeState = true;
            } else {
                this.resetIn();
                this.pinValid = null;
                this.pincodeState = false;
                if (!newPin) {
                    this.pincodeState = null;
                }
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        pincodeValid() {},
    },
};
</script>
```

### Component in Blade file

```
<address-receiver p_old="{{ old('pincode') }}"
                  l_old="{{ old('locality') }}"
                  d_old="{{ old('district') }}"
                  s_old="{{ old('state') }}"
>
</address-receiver>
```

Is there a more elegant way of implementing the old data? I am doing the API call again and getting the options after which the old value is set as the selected value. Any criticism is welcome. I am new to Vue and would love to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:old="{{ json_encode(Session::getOldInput()) }}"` to get old values from session. Other than that try to avoid props like:  `p_old` they break 2 principles:

1. I have no idea for what p stands for
2. It does not follow style guideline of Vue

When you define props as object try to be explicit about type: `String, Array` etc.

Comment: Changed names of the props and added String type. Is it necessary to v-bind since it's going to be string anyways and I don't need to check if old value exists before passing it. If I bind it Vue throws an error when no data exists.

Answer (score 1):

### User Experience

The function method `pincodeSearch` is called whenever the pincode value changes and is vald. It would likely be wise to consider minimizing server requests by debouncing the function and/or cancelling existing requests if the method is called rapidly in short succession.

### Vue / Javascript

It looks like you started to add a computed property `pincodeValid` but didn't implement and use it. It could be something as simple as this example:

```
pincodeValid: function () {
    return this.pincode >= 100000 && this.pincode <= 999999
}
```

then instead of needing the watcher, a method could be added and bound to the `@input` attribute of the pincode input:

```
pincodeChange: function() {
   if (this.pincodeValid) {
        //this should probably be debounced to minimize server requests
        this.pincodeSearch();
        
    }
    else {
        this.resetIn();
        this.pinValid = null
    }
}
```

Then the whole `watch` section can be eliminated.

According to the [VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property):

> When you have some data that needs to change based on some other data, it is tempting to overuse `watch` - especially if you are coming from an AngularJS background. However, it is often a better idea to use a computed property rather than an imperative `watch` callback. <sup>[1](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property)</sup>

While it may not help this situation much, it is better to get into the practice of using computed properties instead of watchers where possible, since "*computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed.*"<sup>[2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)</sup>

---

There is this loop in the callback to the `axios.get()` call:

> ```
> for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
>       this.l_options.push(response.data[i].locality);
> }
> ```

That could be simplified using a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) - e.g.

```
for (const datum of response.data) {
    this.l_options.push(datum.locality);   
}
```

While there may be a slight performance hit due to the iterator it is simpler to read.